# Can I execute a raw MongoDB query in node-mongodb-native driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**FYI - I know how to use the MongoDB driver and know this is not how one would use it in a web app, but this is not for a web app. My aim is to emulate the MongoDB shell in NodeJS**

I'm writing a [DB GUI](https://github.com/nodedb/) and would like to execute a raw MongoDB query, eg `db.tableName.find({ col: 'value' })`. Can I achieve this using the [native MongoDB driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)? I'm using v2.2, which is current the latest version.

If not, how can I achieve this in NodeJS?

Comment: This question seems badly researched to me, you are asking for a tutorial on how to use the node native MongoDB driver basically

Comment: Respectfully, I'm not asking that. I can't find any documentation about how to execute a raw query - my aim is to emulate the MongoDB command line

Comment: Hmm, there is no such thing. You are thinking of how to translate one set of JS into another set of JS. You could easily make a wapper for your program which provides the global objects ready to use as a console emulator, in fact if I remember right MongoDB used to have a test console which did exactly that

Comment: To clarify, a raw query would in fact be pure BSON and would look very different

Comment: I'm guessing that, somewhere inside the MongoDB driver, there will be a socket connection that executes a string. I was hoping that this was publicly accessible - effectively, this would serve the same purpose as a raw "select * from table" in the MySQL driver

Comment: No, this does not exist, instead what exists is a BSON protocol handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note: The question has changed - see the updates below.**

*Original answer:*

Yes.

Instead of:

```
db.tableName.find({ col: 'value' })
```

You use it as:

```
db.collection('tableName').find({ col: 'value' }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        // you have data here
    }
});
```

See: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find

### Update

After you changed your question and posted some comments it is more clear what you want to do.

To achieve your goal of emulating the Mongo shell in Node you would need to parse the command typed by the user and execute the appropriate command while keeping in mind:

1. the difference between SpiderMonkey used by the Mongo shell and Node with V8 and libuv
2. the difference between BSON and JSON
3. the fact that Mongo shell works synchronously and the Node driver works asynchronously

The last part will probably be the hardest part for you. Remember that in the Mongo shell this is perfectly legal:

```
db.test.find()[0].x;
```

In Node the `.find()` method doesn't return the value but it either takes a callback or returns a promise. It will be tricky. The `db.test.find()[0].x;` case may be relatively easy to handle with promises (if you understand the promises well) but this will be harder:

```
db.test.find({x: db.test.find()[0].x});
```

and remember that you need to handle arbitrarily nested levels.

### The Mongo protocol

After reading some of the comments I think it's worth noting that what you actually send to the Mongo server has nothing to do with the JavaScript that you write in the Mongo shell. The Mongo shell uses SpiderMonkey with a number of predefined functions and objects.

But you don't actually send JavaScript to the Mongo server so you can't send things like `db.collection.find()`. Rather you send a binary `OP_QUERY` struct with a collection name encoded as a cstring and a query encoded as BSON plus a bunch of binary flags. See:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#wire-op-query

The BSON is itself a binary format with a number of low level values defined as bytes:

- http://bsonspec.org/spec.html

The bottom line is that you don't send to the Mongo server anything resembling what you enter in the Mongo shell. The Mongo shell parses the things that you type using the SpiderMonkey parser and sends binary requests to the actual Mongo server. The Mongo shell uses JavaScript but you don't communicate with the Mongo server in JavaScript.

### Example

Even the JSON query object is not sent to Mongo as JSON. For example, when you are searching for a document with a `hello` property equal to "world" you would use `{hello: 'world'}` in JavaScript or `{"hello": "world"}` in JSON but this is what gets send to the Mongo server - by the Mongo shell or by any other Mongo client:

```
\x16\x00\x00\x00\x02hello\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00\x00
```

### Why it's so different

To understand why the syntax used in Node is so different from the Mongo shell, see this answer:

- **[Why nodejs-mongodb middleware has different syntax than mongo shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397386/why-nodejs-mongodb-middleware-has-different-syntax-than-mongo-shell/41397565#41397565)**

Comment: That's not the answer I'm looking for. I'm aiming to emulate the MongoDB shell, which is why I want to execute a raw query.

Comment: @RiggerTheGeek The fact that you want to emulate the Mongo shell was added to your question after I posted my answer. Now that I know more about your use case, see my updated answer for info about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: rather than parsing it (and risk getting it wrong), is there a way of just sending the string 'db.table.find()' straight through to the MongoDB instance like you would with a SQL query?

Comment: @RiggerTheGeek You don't send `db.collection.find()` to Mongo. You send things like `OP_QUERY` struct with a collection name as a cstring and a query as BSON plus a bunch of binary flags - see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#wire-op-query This is binary protocol. You don't send anything resembling what you enter in the Mongo shell. The Mongo shell parses the things that you type using the SpiderMonkey parser and sends binary requests to the actual Mongo server. This is not a text protocol. The Mongo shell uses JS but you don't communicate with Mongo in JS.

Comment: @RiggerTheGeek See my updated answer for more info on the actual data that you send to the Mongo server.

Comment: Agree with the question. What if I need 'db.version()' in node.js? How can I do that?